Get Pull requests from bitbucket REST-API assigned to my user
I am using the below REST-API to get the latest pull request from bitbucket
{link}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{my project}/repos/{my repo}/pull-requests?state=all&limit=1&size=1
It is working perfectly fine, but is it possible for this API to set filter so I can filter by my user and to get the pull requests that are only opened from me.
Please let me know if I have to use different API
I checked in the documentation, but did not find such filter https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.16.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm8287391664

A bit late response, but this should do the work:
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests/#api-pullrequests-selected-user-get
However it is marked as deprecated. If you still need help, write a comment and I will try to answer it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
